# Limiting a Firebase Realtime Database Query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way that I can limit a Firebase Database Query to just one child or start at a certain child.

So for example:

I have a user's path with 10 children (which would be the USERS).

- Is there a way to just find the 3rd child in that path?
- Is there a way to find all children after the 3rd child (including the 3rd)?

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is are ways to limit what child nodes are read from a location, by using the Firebase query operations to [order, filter and limit data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

But unlike what you seem to want, these queries are not offset based. So while you can get the first 3 child nodes matching certain conditions, you cannot subsequently request that Firebase **skip** the first 3. Instead, Firebase queries are cursor based, meaning they work from knowing what specific item to start at. What you **can** do is remember the 3rd item of the first page, and then tell Firebase to start returning child nodes from that one onwards.

If you search for Firebase queries and pagination you'll find a lot of material showing how to do this.

Also see:

- [firebase android pagination with recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466540/firebase-android-pagination-with-recyclerview/38469935#38469935)
- [Firebase pagination in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117438/firebase-pagination-in-android/45119251#45119251)
- [How to filter data based on items count in Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308128/how-to-filter-data-based-on-items-count-in-firebase-database/41309106#41309106)
- [How to paginate in Firebase Database #AskFirebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871157/how-to-paginate-in-firebase-database-askfirebase/44871503#44871503)
- and more from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+pagination)